# Click to a new id on an outside HTML page embedded in a div

Tags: css, html, parent-child, nested-class

I have a working image gallery with a thumbs navigation bar below, which includes a mouse rollover effect. When clicking on a thumb, the main image changes by calling up a different div id layout (with a different main background image.) However, I'm running this from a parent HTML page (main page) that swaps to this child HTML in a div. When I try clicking to a new id within the child page, the parent reads it as its own. How can I identify that the href div id is nested in the external/child HTML?

Here is the div used in the child HTML navigation sitting in the parent div, with href pointing to #smooth, etc:

```
<div id="container1">
<ul id="flavors1">
    <nav id="menu2"><ul class="coffeenav"><li class="smooth"><a href="#smooth">Smooth Caffeinator</a></li></ul></nav>
    <nav id="menu2"><ul class="coffeenav"><li class="vanilla"><a href="#vanilla">Vanilla Dream</a></li></ul></nav>
    <nav id="menu2"><ul class="coffeenav"><li class="handsome"><a href="#handsome">Dark and Handsome</a></li></ul></nav>
    <nav id="menu2"><ul class="coffeenav"><li class="dabomb"><a href="#dabomb">Da Bomb</a></li></ul></nav>
    <nav id="menu2"><ul class="coffeenav"><li class="choconut"><a href="#choconut">Choconut</a></li></ul></nav>
</ul>
</div>
```

This is the parent HTML, which includes its own rollover navigation that clicks and calls up the child HTML (where the problem exists -- you'll notice the small thumb navigation does not work):

http://mmdsgn.com/divsample/

And this is the child/nested HTML inside the div, with working nav (only first 3 thumbs):

http://mmdsgn.com/divsample/coffee.html

Comment: Please provide more code in the question. The minimum amount to replicate the problem. Also if you need to provide an example, use a site such as jsfiddle.net so any changes you make while working on this problem on your sample pages won't confuse us.

Comment: Thanks @jon-p. Here's the demo interface stripped down to the minimum elements highlighting the problem: http://mmdsgn.com/divsample/2/

Comment: @jon-p Only the "Wakey Wakey" and "Smooth Caffeinator" buttons function in this demo. When you click on either, the second level UI comes up, which is a new HTML page nested in the parent HTML div id. The two smaller buttons for both flavors should toggle you between two screens, but it's not working. If you play the child/nested page directly, you'll see it working: http://mmdsgn.com/divsample/2/coffee.html

Comment: @jon-p ... I can't figure out where to put code at this level of the discussion, btw. Sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow. Also, building it in jsfiddle.net will require more stripping of various code elements, and I'm not an expert. I'm a designer first. But I will try if you still need this. This is part of a big site project and I'm learning on the fly lots of new CSS/js/jquery stuff.

Answer (score 0):

OK Lets start with your HTML, it is not valid for a start. `ID` should be unique, if it's not unique, use `class` instead. The only valid child elements for `ul` are `li` elements. Further more you have nested `ul` with only one item which does not seem to make sense. Also `nav` is meant to denote a navigation section (http://html5doctor.com/nav-element/) I would recoment seomething like the following:

```
<nav id="container1">
    <ul id="flavors" class="coffeenav">       
        <li class="smooth"><a href="#smooth">Smooth Caffeinator</a></li>
        <li class="vanilla"><a href="#vanilla">Vanilla Dream</a></li>
        <li class="handsome"><a href="#handsome">Dark and Handsome</a></li>
        <li class="dabomb"><a href="#dabomb">Da Bomb</a></li>
        <li class="choconut"><a href="#choconut">Choconut</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Now as to why I think what you are trying to do is a bad idea. You're breaking the back button, which is generaly considered bad form. How does a user navigate backwards using the browser? How will users bookmark their new favourite "Wakey Wakey" coffee page? With the way tou're heading with this, it won't be possible.

If you want to continue down this route investigate the [jquery on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/). This binds event so dynamicaly loaded can have event handlers assigned to them. You would want to use something like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#web').on('click', '#flavors li a', function () {
         $('#web').load('coffee.html #' + $(this).attr('href'));
         return false;
     });
});
```

What this code does is say for any click on `'#flavors li a'` which exist now or in the future within the `#web` element perform the load action. The main difference to what you have at the moment is that `click` binds the event handler to elements that exsit in the DOM when the page is loaded, courtesey of the `document.ready` call. Change or remove elements and the handler binding is broken. Using `on` enables the evenh handler to be bound to dynamicaly added elements.

**Update**

Looking at your latest sample from the comments, it looks like i've made some false assumptions regarding your ID's and have given you a selector for jquery that wont work as the ID's for the navs change, which is OK as ID's are meant to be unique on a page. Looking for the next point of commanality, I can see the "coffeenav" class so lets use this instead....

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#web').on('click', '.coffeenav li a', function () {
         $('#web').load('coffee.html #' + $(this).attr('href'));
         return false;
     });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I'll test it out and get back to you. Regarding the reason I'm going this route, it's a vertically-scrolled web site with all the content stacked and a stationary/fixed header navigation bar linking to each content section, i.e., this coffee flavor UI. The sections slide up/down into place under the header. So, in the end, users won't be able to bookmark that section (or flavor) anyway. The client wanted this type of site.

Comment: Clients, always full of bad ideas! Just make sure they understand the ramifications of their requests. YOu don't want them coming back to you at a later date saying "Why can't I book mark my `Wakey Wakey` Coffee page?"

Comment: Jon, is this CSS and JS for the parent or child HTML? (I'm embedding the JS in the pages for this particular device.) And should I apply the new standards to both, i.e., changing div to nav for the navigation lines and deleting the double ul nesting?

Comment: I'm still having problems. I cleaned up the code for both HTML pages as best I could per your suggestions: http://www.mmdsgn.com/divsample/3/ ... I might start a new question thread and I'll post all of the code.

Comment: I just commented in my other thread... I want to link back out of coffee.html to the parent HTML in the div, to <div id="container">. I have a button all set, but can't figure it out. Can you provide the quick code for this?

Comment: I'd accept this answer for this question and start a new question for,well, your new question.